# bytes sent and received python in ubuntu 14

Tags: python, ubuntu

Hi my problem is with python read the bytes sent and received in ubuntu 14.10 x64 bits.

My code functionally in osx is:

```
  #Network
    net = psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)
    sent = humanize.naturalsize(net['en0'].bytes_sent)
    received = humanize.naturalsize(net['en0'].bytes_recv)
    print(sent)
    print(received)
```

Thankyou

Comment: It works for me. $ uname -a
Linux pc0095725 3.13.0-49-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 20:11:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hardcoding the interface name but ubuntu uses a different naming scheme. On my machine I got

```
>>> psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True).keys()
['lo', 'virbr0', 'eth1', 'eth0']
>>>
```

...and my active interface is `'eth1'`.